# Counting number of null values below and placing them in new df

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, dataframe

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSU6d.png)

I'm attempting to count the number of null values below each non-null cell in a dataframe and put the number into a new variable (size) and data frame.

I have included a picture of the dataframe I'm trying to count. I'm only interested in the Arrival Date Column for now. The new data frame should have a column that has 1,1,3,7..etc as it's first observations.

```
##Loops through all of rows in DOAs
for i in range(0, DOAs.shape[0]):
    j=0
    if DOAs.iloc[int(i),3] != None: ### the rest only runs if the current, i, observation isn't null
        newDOAs.iloc[int(j),0] = DOAs.iloc[int(i),3] ## sets the jth i in the new dataframe to the ith (currently assessed) row of the old
        foundNull = True #Sets foundNull equal to true
        k=1 ## sets the counter of people 
        while foundNull == True and (k+i) < 677: 
                if DOAs.iloc[int(i+k),3] == None: ### if the next one it looks at is null, increment the counter to add another person to the family
                    k = k+1
                else:
                    newDOAs.iloc[int(j),1] = k ## sets second column in new dataframe equal to the size
                    j = j+1
                    foundNull = False
    j=0
```

Comment: please post data, not a picture of your data frame

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working to get one. Can't seem to get it formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is get the indices of non-null entries in whatever column of your dataframe, then get the distances between each. Note: This is assuming they are nicely ordered and/or you don't mind calling `.reset_index()` on your dataframe.

Here is a sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, None, None, None, 2, None, None, 3, None, None]})
not_null_index = df.dropna(subset=['a']).index
null_counts = {}

for i in range(len(not_null_index)):
    if i < len(not_null_index) - 1:
        null_counts[not_null_index[i]] = not_null_index[i + 1] - 1 - not_null_index[i]
    else:
        null_counts[not_null_index[i]] = len(df.a) - 1 - not_null_index[i]

null_counts_df = pd.DataFrame({'nulls': list(null_counts.values())}, index=null_counts.keys())
df_with_null_counts = pd.merge(df, null_counts_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Essentially all this code does is get the indices of non-null values in the dataframe, then gets the difference between each index and the next non-null index and puts that in the column. Then sticks those `null_counts` in a dataframe and merges it with the original.

After running this snippet, `df_with_null_counts` is equal to:

```
     a  nulls
0  1.0      3
4  2.0      2
7  3.0      2
```

Alternatively, you can use numpy instead of using a loop, which would be much faster for large dataframes. Here's a sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, None, None, None, 2, None, None, 3, None, None]})
not_null_index = df.dropna(subset=['a']).index

offset_index = np.array([*not_null_index[1:], len(df.a)])
null_counts = offset_index - np.array(not_null_index) - 1

null_counts_df = pd.DataFrame({'nulls': null_counts}, index=not_null_index)
df_with_null_counts = pd.merge(df, null_counts_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

And the output will be the same.

Comment: This works great! I neglected to mention that I wanted the first non-nulls to be counted as well so that every obs outputted had at least 1, but I took out the minus 1s in your first one and it works like a dream! Thank you!